# How to render language select block in page template?

Tags: theming

**Background information**:
I used the following script to list all the twig blocks: *drush ev "print_r(array_keys(\Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block')->getDefinitions()))*" and when I tried the following twig : *{{ drupal_entity('block', '') }}* and it is not rendering the twig block–

I developed a Twig page in Drupal 8 to allow my website visitors the ability to select the language they want. I downloaded all the multilingual contrib modules.

I am facing two issues:

1. How to render a block in the middle of my twig page to display the language drop-down menu? (I already have a block that displays a drop-down menu language from a contrib module).
2. The CSS background image I had setup is covering one of the Twig field I wanted to test. How can I tweak the CSS in order to display the twig block?

Comment: [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) lets you render blocks in Twig pretty easily. CSS is off-topic. You can't render Drupal blocks with CSS.

Comment: I already have twig tweak module installed and enabled. I was just listing two related issues I am facing right now. I am aware that blocks cannot be rendered by Twig. The image I added as a background is just covering the render twig field.

Comment: I used the following script to list all the twig blocks: drush ev "print_r(array_keys(\Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block')->getDefinitions()));" but I tried the following and it is not rendering the twig block: {{ drupal_entity('block', '<block_id>') }}

Comment: And why is this info missing from your question? Please update your question and add everything you tried yourself so far.

Answer (score 2):

Just place this in the your custom twig page where you want your language switcher links. We are using twig tweak module here. So intall this module before adding this line:

`{ # Language switcher # }`

```
{{ drupal_block('language_block:language_interface', wrapper=false) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

`drupal_entity()` is for rendering entities. For rendering block plugins use `drupal_block()` instead.
The difference is explained very well in the following guide.
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/rendering-blocks-with-twig-tweak

Comment: thank you for your help.